# Find the list of the keywords from a text and list them in an array in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to find the list of keywords I have specified in a column and want to find if the text has them or not. If yes, how many times the keywords are used?

Here is the screenshot of what I want to acheive:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/umfsf84iljdc8wh/Screenshot%202019-11-17%2023.30.29.png?dl=0

My List in saved column (column 1)

```
>  Apple, Mango, Banana
```

Input 1:

```
I like Apple and mango. I bought a mango yesterday
```

Result 1:

```
["Apple - 1", "Mango -2 "]
```

I don't want unique frequency of the occurrences, but as many as it occurs. Also I don't want it to be case sensitive.

I have tried many ways but failed.

Any ideas to achieve this? Shall I try VB? I am trying in excel

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for a Scripting Dictionary. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: not yet. but i can try

Comment: Good use case for regular expressions too or a rather long TEXTJOIN formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I probably went overboard with this but you could try the below, using both @BraX his recommendation of a scripting dictionary and my own using regular expressions:

---

***<sub>Sample data:</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>Code:</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, arr3() As Variant
Dim lr As Long, x As Long, y As Long
Dim regex As Object: Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheet1 'Change to whatever CodeName your sheet has

    'Set global parameter of regex to true
    regex.Global = True

    'Get array of list
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = .Range("A2:A" & lr).Value

    'Get array to loop through
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    arr2 = .Range("B2:B" & lr).Value
    ReDim arr3(UBound(arr2) - 1)

    'Loop over both arrays in memory
    For y = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        For x = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)

            'Set regular expression pattern and count matches
            regex.Pattern = "\b" & LCase(arr1(x, 1)) & "\b"
            Set matches = regex.Execute(LCase(arr2(y, 1)))

            'Only add to dictionary if at least one occurence
            If matches.Count > 0 Then
                dict("""" & arr1(x, 1) & " - " & matches.Count & """") = 1
            End If

        Next x

        'Add all to a a third array and clear dictionary
        arr3(y - 1) = "[" & Join(dict.Keys, ", ") & "]"
        dict.RemoveAll

    Next y

    'If all looping is done, transpose arr3 to result target
    .Cells(2, 3).Resize(UBound(arr3) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr3)

End With

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Result:</sub>***

[image]

---

Good luck, happy coding =).

Comment: If the op won't vote for it, then I will... Superb, well done.

Comment: Hey, thanks alot. I am new to VBA. tried to have this on google sheet, here is the error it gives https://www.dropbox.com/s/kac52jqkwv4pkr8/Screenshot%202019-11-18%2012.34.10.png?dl=0

Comment: missing ; before statement. line 1, file macros

Comment: @user3415869, google script is sicnificantly different to VBA, please note you have tagged Excel and VBA, not GS. There are function in GS that handle regular expressions though.

Comment: As a MAC user i wont be able to use excel :) GS is the only option on my end. I am sure your solution is great, and works. would be awesome if you could adopt it to GS if possible. Thanks alot!

Comment: my bad. its my ignorance, it should have tagged GS. didnt know they are different.

Comment: alright then. i am not sure if i should mark the answer correct for now. will get it in coming days.

Comment: @user3415869, you should mark a question as answered when you feel your question has been answered. There is no pressure to mark as answered. If google sheets is your application of preference, you might even want to consider opening another question.